# How can I change tracking (letter spacing) for unicode-math with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, letterspacing

I'm using a text font for math with `unicode-math`.
I tried setting the math font with option `LetterSpace`, but `unicode-math` doesn't care about font feature settings of text fonts...

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{pala.ttf}[LetterSpace=10]
\setmathfontface\test{pala.ttf}[LetterSpace=10]

\begin{document}

abcdefg

$\test{abcdefg}$

\end{document}
```

Is there any other way to change tracking in math mode?

Comment: as it's a text font don't you want to use `$x + \text{\test abc}$` so the font uses text settings?

Comment: In principle that works. However, within formulas it gets quite cumbersome. Using `\mathrm` makes it a bit easier but it's still not very practicable. I guess the best thing to do then is to write a parser for it.